# Can't Assign Roles discord.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I was testing this code yesterday and it worked perfectly, but today something went wrong and I don't know where.

The bot automatically sends a message, adds 1 reaction, but the problem is that while reacting that there is no assigned role.

My code :

```
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.WebSocket
Imports Discord.Rest

Dim discord As DiscordSocketClient
Public ReactionMessages As ULong

Public token_ As String = "Token_Hiden"

Public Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task
    If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
        Dim reaction As SocketReaction
        Dim rMessage = CType(Await message.Channel.GetMessageAsync(message.Id), RestUserMessage)

        If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") AndAlso
            reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then
        End If

    End If


Private Async Function ReactionAdded(cache As Cacheable(Of IUserMessage, ULong), channel As ISocketMessageChannel, reaction As SocketReaction) As Task
    If Not reaction.User.IsSpecified Then Return

    If ReactionMessages.Contains(cache.Id) Then
        Dim role As IRole = Nothing

        If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then

            role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "one")
        ElseIf reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then

            role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "two")
        End If

        If role IsNot Nothing Then Await DirectCast(reaction.User.Value, SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role)
    End If
End Function

     Private Async Function ReactionRemoved(cache As Cacheable(Of IUserMessage, ULong), channel As ISocketMessageChannel, reaction As SocketReaction) As Task
    If Not reaction.User.IsSpecified Then Return

    If ReactionMessages.Contains(cache.Id) Then
        Dim role As IRole = Nothing
        Dim user As SocketGuildUser = reaction.User.Value

        If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then

            role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "one")
        ElseIf reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") Then

            role = DirectCast(channel, SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "two")
        End If

        If role IsNot Nothing AndAlso user.Roles.Any(Function(r) r.Id = role.Id) Then Await user.RemoveRoleAsync(role)
    End If
End Function



Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim builder = New EmbedBuilder
        builder.WithTitle("test")
        builder.AddField("title!", "not much")
        builder.WithThumbnailUrl(discord.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl)
        builder.WithColor(124, 54, 42)

        Dim msgg = Await discord.GetGuild("426511769687556100").GetTextChannel("534344526848851988").SendMessageAsync("", False, builder)
        Dim my_emo1 As New Emoji("")
        Dim my_emo2 As New Emoji("")

        Await msgg.AddReactionAsync(my_emo1)
        Await msgg.AddReactionAsync(my_emo2)
End Sub
```

This code worked yesterday but I may have changed it a little. If a a user reacts to the new message, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you review the code example that you've posted. There are quite a few errors in there that I'm not sure that would even compile. For instance, you have 2 `ReactionAdded` functions, and the first one is nested inside the `onMsg` function. The nesting is also incorrect as there's only one `EndFunction` and not two.

Comment: @Anu6is, excuse me, i didnt sleepy as well, i updated the last edition , please check again.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the intent of code in `onMsg`. `reaction` is declared but not used. You are using the `message` parameter provided to the function to retrieve itself. You call `GetMessageAsync(message.id)` with the id of an already existing message object. This is essentially retrieving the same message you already have. Also you don't actually do anything with the rMessage variable once retrieved. The `ReactionMessages` field is declared as a ULong, however you are referencing it in `ReactionAdded` and `ReactionRemoved` as if it were a List. It is also appears to be never set.

Comment: you was right, i now can track last message id, and now can handle the reaction, how can i usemulti id variable, because this not work "ReactionMessages = msg.Id" its only for single track last id, how to get all id not only last one, it by ( List(Of ULong) ), can you explain how to use it

Comment: Declare the field like `Public ReactionMessages As New List(Of ULong)` and instead of `ReactionMessages = msg.id` you would use `ReactionMessages.Add(msg.id)`.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figure out that must to add,

```
ReactionMessages = msg.Id 'after Await Msg, [single msg track id]

ReactionMessages.Add(msg.Id) 'after Await Msg, [Multi msgs track id] By @Anu6is| Thanks.
```